# javascript: dynamic generation of \xdd symbols

Tags: javascript, string, escaping

My script is building a file that consists of bytes \xdd where dd - hex number.
The problem is obvious:

```
"\x" + "4c" != "\x4c" ;
```

and therefore I can generate a byte only using
huge array like

```
{ 
    '00' : '\x00',
    '01' : '\x01',
    ... etc. 
}
```

Is there a better solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [`String.fromCharCode`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/fromCharCode) which can turn a Unicode codepoint (in the BMP) into the appropriate "character" (string with a length of one).

Note that in JavaScript a string is a sequence of Unicode codepoints *in the BMP*. Characters requiring surrogate pairs are another story. The link includes a "fix" for this.

```
String.fromCharCode(0x42) == "\x42" // true
```

Happy coding.

Comment: thank you! I have only symbols from 0x00 to 0xff so I don't need this fix